# Amazon SWF vs Data Pipeline for Pig Scripts

Tags: amazon-swf, amazon-data-pipeline

Hi have a daily data import pig script that I  want to run on Amazon EMR.  Should I use Simple Workflow or Data Pipeline to schedule and monitor the job?  I tried going through data pipeline but it seems to require an output.. what goes into this output if I'm running a custom pig script?  Are they expecting you to use a default pre-made pig script for data import tasks/jobs?

In my case I have a pig script that fetches from an S3 input and does some data transformations which push out to dynamodb.  Trying to schedule this pig script in data pipeline, I see there is a pig activity type and a s3 to dynamodb template but I'm not sure how to customize/modify it so that it runs my pig script and transforms the data before it goes to dynamo db.  Where is the s3 and dynamodb mappping set in this process?  Is it redundant since the pig script imports from s3 and exports to dynamodb all by itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Workflow is useful for managing workflows. In *very* simple terms, it is a queue with a lot of features like history tracking, signalling, timers etc.

Data Pipeline is useful when you need an ETL kind engine. It provides you capabilities of scheduling tasks on a periodic basis, handle dependencies between different tasks and failure-retry handling. It also allows you to not worry about resources like launching and shutting down EMR / EC2.

You can always build all these things on top of SWF by writing your own state machine. But IMO, it's better to use Data Pipeline for your use case.

---

For running a custom Pig job using Data Pipeline, you should be able to disable staging.

> stage = false

'stage' is an optional field on PigActivity.

```
{
  "name": "DefaultActivity",
  "id": "ActivityId_1",
  "type": "PigActivity",
  "stage": "false",
  "scriptUri": "s3://bucket/query",
  "scriptVariable": [
    "param1=value1",
    "param2=value2"
  ],
  "schedule": {
    "ref": "ScheduleId_l"
  },
  "runsOn": {
    "ref": "EmrClusterId_1"
  }
}
```